# Hyperemia of conjunctiva increases during evening and near work, why?

Tags: opthalmology

My book Parson Diseases of eye 23rd ed says pg141

> hyperaemia primarily or as a result of underlying aetiology, causes a sense of discomfort often described as tightness, grittiness, inability to keep the eyes open and tiredness, especially towards the evening or after near work.

Is it because of tiredness of ciliary muscles? Or it is that throughout the day offending agent accumulates?

Comment: I'm not in any manner a qualified individual on this sector, but I do have something to share that may or may not contribute to getting an answer to your question.  I used to work 60+ hours in my hayday at a deskjob, and experienced exactly those symptoms close to a daily basis.  I was recommended a brand of optical lenses that significantly reduced said symptoms, and although there are many claims as to the "proprietary" design and characteristics involved, ...

Comment: an objestive comparison led me to note that the primary difference between my current and previous lenses in the physical aspect was an adjustment to the pupilary distance by 5 units.  The logic behind the adjustment was actually surprisingly simple: most general-use lenses assume a fairly varied mix of long and short distance viewing as you travel about throught your day, looking at varying objects at varying distances.   The adjustment mentioned above accounts for longer or more frequent focusing at a closer range, therefore eliminating some of the ...

Comment: strain that would have resulted from the usage bias.  Not sure if that at all helps or is just completely irrelevant, but good luck!